# Tumblr's pixel-by-pixel arrow

Tags: html, css, tumblr

If you check out here:

[http://www.tumblr.com/explore](http://web.archive.org/web/20111102162310/http://www.tumblr.com/explore)

You'll notice the background box and little triangle over the "explore" menu item. I absolutely love Tumblr's design, so I've been trying to learn what I can from it. When I used Chrome's handy developer's tools, I saw that, for the little triangle, they "drew" it pixel by pixel. They have 6 divs a pixel tall. The first is 11 pixels wide, the second is 9, the third 7...

This raises all sorts of little flags in my head, but I've only just gotten into web development, so I figured I would ask people who know more about it.

So, all you pros out there, what are the pros and cons of doing a design pixel by pixel with HTML elements instead of using an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantages are that it will be identical across browsers, even IE6, and it doesn't make an extra HTTP request for the background image method.

The drawback, of course, is an increased HTML and CSS weight, decreased semantics, and a messier-looking code. A better alternative, even to using an image, would be to use a pseudo-element, shaped to look like a triangle. It wouldn't take away from a clean code, or semantics.

Comment: How would you use a pseudo-element to make a triangle? And how long have they been supported?

Comment: CSS arrow borders don't always turn out symmetric.  It's one of the reasons I don't like VideoJS.

Comment: @BrianNickel: Look at the link that ANeves posted - it's perfectly symmetrical.

Comment: Okay, for this application it isn't an issue but for other applications it can be.  The left border takes up the whole height of the object, meaning the top and bottom borders take up `(width - 1px)` and the right border takes up `(height - 2px)`.  This is why VideoJS looks so bad.

Answer (score 0):

While this does achieve transparency in IE6 as others point out, this is not very convincing since you could always use a transparent GIF for this application.

I would say that this hack is here to have one less call to the server.  This has two main benefits:

- Instant visibility.  If all the information you need to render the image is in the CSS and HTML, it can render as soon as possible.  There is no additional network call.
- Getting out of the critical path.  This page has a lot of files to load.  Since browsers limit the number of concurrent connections to a server, any file you can remove from the startup process will improve load time.

An alternative would be to use a data URL holding a transparent PNG.  This is better in that it doesn't depend on a hack but worse in that IE6 and IE7 can't support it.  A more common practice is to bundle all images used by the page in a sprite image and use CSS backgrounds with `background-position` to crop out the exact image.  This has the disadvantage of still requiring a network call but could be bundled with a data URL if you don't need IE6 or IE7.

The disadvantage of course is that this is a hack and isn't the right way of doing things.

In summary:

#### PROS

- Fast rendering
- No network call needed
- Improved page load time
- Cross browser support

#### CONS

- It's just not how you're supposed to do things.

I personally love it and would totally do something like it if I had to.